# How to bypass Woocommerce checkout validation from the plugin?

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, validation

I need to bypass any validation process in Woocommerce checkout page when **Process Order** button clicked. What filter or action hooks should I use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know it's the best way to do or not, but it worked for me.

```
 add_filter('woocommerce_after_checkout_validation', 'additional_validation'));
 function additional_validation($fields)
 {
     // bypass all error returned
     wc_clear_notices();
 }
```